Make Chandelier Wiring Longer
I want to add another 12" section of metal rod to lower this chandelier so it's closer to the table it hangs over. However, the wires that pass through the rods are too short. The rods are quite slender and there is little room in them after passing through the three wires. Is there a way to extend the wire without rewiring the entire fixture? Thanks for any advice. 

I don't have time to write a full answer, so just a suggestion: Instead of lengthening the chandelier, build a box under the existing junction box location and mount the chandelier to the bottom of that box.

open up at the ceiling, do not remove the old wires, solder extension wires to it and slip a heat-shrink tube over each connection. insert the rod extension, – probably not up to code, so your choice

How are the wires connected at in the junction at the bottom of the fixture (where the up wires connect to the cross pieces to the individual lights)?
If the up wire is connected with wire nuts to the cross beam wiring, you should be able to replace the up wire with a longer one.  If the junction is soldered together that may be more than a beginner project.

Following up on DIY75's not-to-code solder and heat-shrink solution:  you may want to split each of the 3 wires at slightly different lengths, so the solder points do not overlap.

Replace the wires at far as they run.
I'm  expecting a junction of some sort in the barrel part, replace the wires back to that.

You'll need to replace those wires entirely with longer ones - there isn't a code-compliant way to splice them inside the drop pole.

Ugh, not what I was hoping to hear. I don't know where to begin to rewire from the ground up. Thank you.

@KathiM - get an electrician?

@KathiM I imagine it won't be any trickier than rewiring a plug, which even for a UK plug isn't very hard. https://www.checkatrade.com/blog/how-to/wire-plug/ And to be honest if you think that those instructions for rewiring a plug are hard then you should definitely get an electrician.

Thanks to all who made suggestions. I've decided to change the fixture in that space and use this shorter fixture at a location with a lower ceiling.

Code requires there to be a junction box above the part attached to the ceiling. There are wire nuts in there connecting the in-wall wiring to the fan wiring.

Only continue if you are comfortable working with home wiring.It’s not hard! But you must be confident you can open something up and put it back together. And be comfortable around home/120V electrical wiring.
Get a friend or family member to help you.
Find and turn off the power to the lamp at the breaker box.I have worked as an electrical apprentice and have worked on live wires plenty of times, but we will always turn off the power at the breaker box for things like this. Don’t skip it.
Use a sturdy stool or step ladder to put your head just under the ceiling.
Unscrew and lower the ceiling-attached part of the fan (your friend or family member can hold its weight for you while you work).
Use a multimeter (or a voltage tester, cheap from store) to verify that the wires are not still hot!
Take a picture of the wiring in the junction box. You should have:

a white wire
a green or bare copper wire
a black or red wire (or one of each)


Unscrew the wire connectors for each of the wires, one at a time. Screw it back on to the wire once you have the lamp’s wire disconnected.
Take down your lamp.

At this point you can take your time extending and rewiring your lamp. Use the same color wires when you replace them. (Or, at minimum, make sure you can tell them apart and match the new wires up to the ones you replaced!)
When you are finished, reinstall it by performing the above steps in reverse order. Make sure to refer to your picture on your phone when putting the wires back in.
After screwing the wires back together with the wire caps, verify that they are properly joined by attempting to gently pull each wire out of the connector. They should not budge. Also, except for the green/copper wire, you should not see any bare wire outside of the cap. If you do, make sure to either unscrew and clip the wire shorter or wrap the cap and wire with electrical tape.
If you are satisfied that you put everything back together correctly, go turn on the breaker and test the lamp with the wall switch.
It should go without saying that doing this stuff yourself you assume the risk that, if you mess up, you may blow a breaker or fry your lamp. Or even possibly start a fire — for this purpose you should also have a fire extinguisher with electrical rating (your standard ABC extinguisher will do, the ‘C’ is for ‘electrical’). Having your friend/family member next to the switch to immediately turn it off if you should detect sparks or smoke or electrical/burning smell will help. tl;dr don’t mess up.

I was going to suggest checking for the junction box, good to know code requires it. Should be obvious but I would add to be explicit, OP should only do this if he's comfortable and knowledgeable enough with home/120V wiring.
